# How to set color of a row based on it's class name?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the color of a table row if this row has a class that name is the RGB code?

For example:

```
<tr class="#0DFF39">....
```

I can't set `background-color` directly and this is the closest I could get. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: no, not possible

Comment: If you are able to assign this value to `class` why not to `style`?

Comment: @Greedo I use Vuetify data table and I can set only a class.

Comment: do you have any callbacks in Vuetify data table for each row rendering?

Comment: There's an experimental proposal for something like that using the `attr()` css function, but it's not really supported by browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr check last example (`attr` works but only for the `content` property). So I don't think there's a clean way to do what you want.

Comment: @Milano How does your code looks like, that you just can change the class of the `tr` element?

Answer (score 1):

you should create pre-defined class named by colors, for exemple :

```css
.red{
  background-color: #9E1200;
}

.blue{
  background-color: #3FB8B4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="red">
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <th>Title 2</th>
    <th>Title 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blue">
    <td>Exemple 1</td>
    <td>Exemple 2</td>
    <td>Exemple 3</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: 3 upvotes for an answer that is far from answering the question .. quite suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact solution but it can give you some insights on how it can be done. You mentioned that you are using Vuetify data table, so if it provides any callback for each row rendered then you can simply replace this codes onclick with that callback function and you are done, otherwise I believe this is not possible.

```js
 function changeBgColor(theElement)
     {  theElement.style.backgroundColor=theElement.className
     }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="#9E1200" onclick="changeBgColor(this)">
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <th>Title 2</th>
    <th>Title 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="#3FB8B4" onclick="changeBgColor(this)">
    <td>Example 1</td>
    <td>Example 2</td>
    <td>Example 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS variables in this case like the following example. But keep in mind [where you can use CSS variables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

```js
var $colorPicker = $('#color-picker').on('change', changeTableRowColor);

function changeTableRowColor() {
  var selectedColor = $colorPicker.val(),
    $targetRows = $('table tr.bg-custom'),
    numberRows = $targetRows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberRows; i++) {
    $targetRows[i].style.setProperty('--bg-color', selectedColor);
  }

}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.bg-custom td {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  border-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="color-picker">
  Select a color
  <input type="color" name="color-picker" id="color-picker" value="#0DFF39" />
</label>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-custom" style="--bg-color: #0dff39;">
    <td>04</td>
    <td>05</td>
    <td>06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>07</td>
    <td>08</td>
    <td>09</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-custom" style="--bg-color: #0dff39;">
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```